# How to make absolute import modules with "moduleDirectories" in a CRA application for JEST

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app, ts-jest

I created some utils for my tests. I'd like to import my utils in such a way

```
import CustomRender from 'my-local-utils'
```

The directory would be

```
-src
 - components
  - __tests__
-test
  -my-loca-utils.js
```

Normally I would include **tests** into the jest.config.js in **moduleDirectories** so it is resolved as global. I've actually seen some StackOverflow answers saying that with CRA it should just be used in the package.json -> **jest**. However, it seems that the object only supports coverage fields. See the message below:

```
Out of the box, Create React App only supports overriding these Jest options:

  • clearMocks
  • collectCoverageFrom
  • coveragePathIgnorePatterns
  • coverageReporters
  • coverageThreshold
  • displayName
  • extraGlobals
  • globalSetup
  • globalTeardown
  • moduleNameMapper
  • resetMocks
  • resetModules
  • restoreMocks
  • snapshotSerializers
  • transform
  • transformIgnorePatterns
  • watchPathIgnorePatterns.

These options in your package.json Jest configuration are not currently supported by Create React App:

  • moduleDirectories

If you wish to override other Jest options, you need to eject from the default setup. You can do so by running npm run eject but remember that this is a one-way operation. You may also file an issue with Create React App to discuss supporting more options out of the box.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by doing the following in your `package.json`:

```
{
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper" {
      "my-local-utils": "<rootDir>/test/my-loca-utils.js"
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I kept what I think it's a typo in your file structure.